# Error when closing FancyBox-iframe after video ends only in IE

Tags: jquery, magento, iframe, fancybox

I am on Magento 1.6.2. with FancyBox 1.3.4.

When in IE8, I click on the closing button showed by FancyBox, I receive next error:
I am not alowed o insert images si I have to list the error:

- An error has occured in the script on this page
- Line: 1
- Char: 1
- Error: Access is denied
- Code: 0
- URL:
  http://www.ingenium.ro/jwplayer/player.swf?allowscriptaccess=always&skin=/jwplayer/skin/slim.zip&width=746&height=430&file=/video/ServerRack.flv&controlbar=over&
- Do you want to continue running scripts on this page?
- YES / NO

In Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari my site do not show any error, the video can be opened and closed anytime.
Please give me some clue how to solve this problem.

FancyBox embeding code:

```
jQuery("a[rel=iframe_flv_digitus]").fancybox({
    'type': 'iframe',
    'width': 746,
    'height': 430,
    'transitionIn' : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut' : 'elastic',
    'overlayColor': '#000000',
    'overlayOpacity': '0.4',
    'padding' : 0,
    'wmode': 'transparent',
    'scrolling': 'no',
    centerOnScroll: true
});
```

Calling the video:

```
<p><a rel="iframe_flv_digitus" href="/jwplayer/player.swf?allowscriptaccess=always&amp;skin=/jwplayer/skin/slim.zip&amp;width=726&amp;height=410&amp;file=/jwplayer/ServerRack.flv"&amp;controlbar=over&amp;autostart=true"><img src="/media/wysiwyg/biometrics/label_view_short_video-en_100.png" alt="digitus" /></a></p>
```

My page where the problem can be seen:
[MyPage](http://www.ingenium.ro/db-nexus-networked-access-control-for-managing-monitoring-and-reporting.html?___store=gb&___from_store=ro)

Please scroll down and click on:

- View Short Video

Comment: this `new Ajax.Updater(a,b,{ ... })` is not properly closed ... you commented out the closing `}` bracket ... so that triggers a js error

Answer (score 0):

After debugging your web page, there's an error in the js file scp_product_extension.js, line 321:

```
if(productId) {
        new Ajax.Updater(destElement, imgUrl, {
            method: 'get',

            /* Cristian - inlocuiesc linia de mai jos cu cea de sub ea pentru ca in SCP dupa alegerea unei optiuni sa pot descide specificatiile in lightbox */
            /*evalScripts: false,*/
            evalScripts: true,
            /* end Cristian*/

            /*onComplete: function() {
                //Product.Zoom needs the *image* (not just the html source from the ajax)
                //to have loaded before it works, hence image object and onload handler
                if ($('image')){
                    var imgObj = new Image();
                    /*imgObj.onload = function() {product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint'); };
                    imgObj.src = $('image').src; ----- Cristian - am renuntat la aceasta instructiune pentru a putea utiliza lightbox in SCP dupa selectarea unei optiuni
                } else {
                    destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
                    /*product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint')----- Cristian - am renuntat la aceasta instructiune pentru a putea utiliza lightbox in SCP dupa selectarea unei optiuni
                }
          }
        }*/);
   } else {
    destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
    /*product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint');----- Cristian - am renuntat la aceasta instructiune pentru a putea utiliza lightbox in SCP dupa selectarea unei optiuni*/
}
```

};

Change this conditional block to:

```
if(productId) {
        new Ajax.Updater(destElement, imgUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            /* Cristian - inlocuiesc linia de mai jos cu cea de sub ea pentru ca in SCP dupa alegerea unei optiuni sa pot descide specificatiile in lightbox */
            /*evalScripts: false,*/
            evalScripts: true
            /* end Cristian*/

            /*onComplete: function() {
                //Product.Zoom needs the *image* (not just the html source from the ajax)
                //to have loaded before it works, hence image object and onload handler
                if ($('image')){
                    var imgObj = new Image();
                    /*imgObj.onload = function() {product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint'); };
                    imgObj.src = $('image').src; ----- Cristian - am renuntat la aceasta instructiune pentru a putea utiliza lightbox in SCP dupa selectarea unei optiuni
                } else {
                    destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
                    /*product_zoom = new Product.Zoom('image', 'track', 'handle', 'zoom_in', 'zoom_out', 'track_hint')----- Cristian - am renuntat la aceasta instructiune pentru a putea utiliza lightbox in SCP dupa selectarea unei optiuni
                }
          }*/
        });
   } else {
    destElement.innerHTML = defaultZoomer;
}
```

Comment: Thanks chridam. Unfortunately after making the correction nothing changed. I receive the same error in IE.

Comment: I can see you have commented out the whole block, could not debug any further the new error `Access is denied. player.swf, line 1 character 1` Is it possible for you to revert your changes to reflect the fix above, so that I can actually trace the error without commenting out the whole block?

Comment: Yes I shall come back to the above situation. I am looking also for another fix, concerning SCP and JQuerry Fancybox. After making a selection into a configurable product, Fancybox is not more working. Now the code is already like above and I shall wait till I see your answer here. Thanks.